# PHP Get Username from another website

Tags: php

My question is how do I get my Username and password from one php page that checks to see if the username and password is correct then to another which simply prints out what the user typed in on the page before.

I don't want to use 'include' because that executes my entire php file which will not work because it runs the login form twice and it then redirects me to my invalid login form page.

Comment: Post the code you're trying so we can give suggestions.

Comment: So... what have you tried? There are thousands of scripts, tutorials, and pages of documentation available with a minimal searching effort.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

```
<?php //one page
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = 'some data';

<?php //another page
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['something'];
//outputs 'some data'
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I think I am doing something wrong in the process here is my code if you could take a look please.

Comment: I am new to all of this so how do you put a block of code in a response and in a question?

Comment: @user1831285 add it to your question, see the [editing guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from more info.